# How to iterate over matrix field from a plugin

Tags: plugin-development, matrix

I'm writing a plugin where I have the id of an entry, that entry has a matrix field, and I want to iterate over the blocks of the matrix field. In php. How do I do that? Pointers to good documentation for how to do this would be appreciated too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, first you want to get the entry model using your entry id. In the EntriesService there is a method called [`getEntryById`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/apis/entriesservice#getEntryById) which you can use like so:

```
$entry = craft()->entries->getEntryById(123);
```

This will return you an [EntryModel](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/entrymodel) which has on it all your fields. So, if you matrix field handle is called `matrixFieldHandle` then you would access the field contents like so:

```
$matrixBlocks = $entry->matrixFieldHandle;
```

A matrix field will return you an array of [MatrixBlockModels](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/matrixblockmodel) from which you can get at everything else you need e.g.:

```
foreach ($matrixBlocks as $block){
  echo $block->id;
  echo $block->fieldHandle;
}
```

Note that to play with block types you will need to look at the [MatrixService](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/apis/matrixservice) and [`getBlockTypeById()`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/apis/matrixservice#getBlockTypeById) to do things like filter out different blocks based on their block types.

Comment: It was that `$matrixBlocks = $entry->matrixFieldHandle;` I was missing. Thanks!!

Comment: No problem! Glad you got it sorted :)